# JavaScript: How to delay a function?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions in Javascript code one looped in the other.

Something like:

```
function doThis(){
   doThat();          
   window.setTimeout( doThis , 2000); 
}

function doThat(){
   if(someCondition){
   window.clearTimeout(id)
   }
   var id = window.setTimeout( doThat, 10000);
}
```

What exactly I want to do:
`doThis` is called as soon as the `window` is loaded. Now, as soon as it is called, it should hand over the control to `doThat()` which waits for 10 seconds before executing again.

Now, `doThat()` is executed till the `if` codition is satisfied. And then, it should hand the control back to `doThis()` which should then wait for 2 seconds and repeat this cycle over and over.

I do not want to use jQuery(callback or chaining stuff) or any other javaScript libarary.How to do this?

Comment: "executed till the `if` is satisfied"?  How, the code doesn't do that.  And you absolutely mustn't put your code into a busy loop waiting for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly,

```
function first() {
    setTimeout(second, 1000)
}

function second() {
    if(condition) {
        setTimeout(first, 2000)
    } else {
        setTimeout(second, 10000)
    }
}
```

No need to save the timeout anywhere or to clear it.

Comment: in  'first()', you did 'setTimeout(second, 1000)'. Could you please explain me what is that for? I will lose 1 second for no reason. Isn't it?

Comment: @NavneetSaini: I misread your explanation then. It would help if you provided your actual code, because currently the first function makes no sense at all.

Comment: I got an idea how to do it, if it doesnt work, I will return back. Thanks for your response:)

Comment: of course, if `first` does _nothing_ except create the timer, it's unnecessary...

Answer (score 0):

Using `setInterval()` might be more appropriate: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: using `setInterval` is almost never more appropriate.

Comment: @Alnitak What do you mean?

Comment: @NavneetSaini because `setInterval` does not provide reliable timing when tabs are hidden, etc.

Comment: @Alnitak, so what could be the better way to execute above thing, then?